# Use a converter to hide a grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, converters

I have a grid like this :

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition />
     <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="12,0,0,10" x:Name="TxtBox_Email"  Text="{Binding m_strMail}"  />
</Grid>
```

I would like to hide the entire grid if the variable binded is empty.
I think i need to use a converter, but i need some help for the syntax.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you're right. You can write a converter like so:

```cs
public class StringLengthVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strValue = value as String;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //We can't support this
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a resource to your page:

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:StringLengthVisibilityConverter x:Key="LengthConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Substitute `local` for an xmlns that points to the CLR namespace of your converter.

After that, we can use our converter in the grid:

```xml
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=m_strMail, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought it could be with less code ! Is there a way to do only in XAML ? Thanks

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni Unfortunately not. C# (or VB.NET) has to get involved at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write it only in xaml when you create a Style for the Grid. But you have to write a Style foreach different Binding. The Viewmodel in this example simply contains a string Property with the name MyString.

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayGroundSecond">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SimpleViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyOwnTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyString}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyString}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyOwnTextBlockStyle}" Text="MyText"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I think vcsjones' solution is better, because you can use it for every Binding and in my solution you have to write a Style with 2 DataTriggers foreach Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Without Converter you can use like this

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=m_strMail}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="12,0,0,10" x:Name="TxtBox_Email"  Text="{Binding m_strMail}"  />
        </Grid>
```